# WPF Desktop Application Will not start in Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, runtime-error

I wrote a WPF C# application in visual studio 2010, but it will not start up on my Windows 10 Machine. I ran into this issue a while back on a different computer, and installing Direct X 9 fixed my issue, this time it did not. I tried compatibility mode, no luck. I also tried adding some exception handling to the initialization of the program like I've read on some other posts here, but it does not seem to even make it to that point when I start the app. This is what I do for that, I get no pop ups at all:

```
        protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("OnInitialized");
        // hook on error before app really starts
        base.OnInitialized(e);
    }

    public override void BeginInit()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("BeginInit");
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
        Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Current_DispatcherUnhandledException);

        base.BeginInit();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("OnSourceInitialized");

        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    }

    void Current_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message);
    }

    void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // put your tracing or logging code here (I put a message box as an example)
        MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
    }
```

When I look in the event viewer, I get two errors an Application Error:

> Faulting application name: BuildingManagerWPF.exe, version: 1.0.0.0,
>   time stamp: 0x59e6d248 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   10.0.14393.479, time stamp: 0x58256d37 Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x000da832 Faulting process id: 0x218 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01d347c8387ca8a0 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Users\lattepanda\Desktop\Building\BuildingManagerWPF.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   08f61ca3-5455-4f5c-98df-1195f203d482 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

And a .NET Runtime Error:

> Application: BuildingManagerWPF.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException    at
>   BuildingManagerWPF.MainWindow..ctor()
>
> Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader,
>   System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object,
>   System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader,
>   Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel,
>   System.Uri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream,
>   System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream,
>   System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri, Boolean)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()    at
>   System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr,
>   IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr,
>   Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>   at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
>   ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run()    at BuildingManagerWPF.App.Main()

Comment: BuildingManagerWPF?

Comment: What's in your `MainWindow`'s constructor?

Comment: Threw visual studio on the machine I was running the applciation on, and it it turns out there were some issues the reference for sqlserverCE. Nothing I believe anyone would have been able to guess at.

Answer (score 0):

If your Visual Studio 2010 isn't updated to SP1 then please try that to begin with:
[Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (KB2736182)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34677)

But perhaps you should consider updating the visual studio version to a newer one...?
[Visual Studio Downloads](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)

Good luck!

Comment: Are you sure this is the error cause? If not, you shouldn't post it as an answer.